# Get file path from Response Header Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I want to pass out the one url from C# webclient or anything else. After that I want to get ResponseHeader in Location path.

Please see below images.
In this image general to Get call from "https://manybooks.net/books/get/232281/6" and get ResponseHeader with Location path.
So i want the Location path using C#.

[Excepted Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFZj3.png)

This is full response and request header and request for reference
[Full Request and Response Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWQPW.png)

Comment: Do you want location header in your C# code?

Comment: Yes I want location in response header. see image I pass out one simple url with "get " and response header will get location.

Comment: Try this code `string location = response.Headers.GetValues("location").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks but  How to call "https://manybooks.net/books/get/232281/6" with "GET method and how to get response. or which methods

Comment: Do you know how to make HTTP calls using `HttpClient` in C#

Comment: When I call Http client so error getting like Additional information: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: You are getting 403 because of authorization. Are you sure you have access or maybe you need to pass some request headers in your code?

Comment: No I can not passout header that way i m giving full screenshot and you make reponseheader with code so i will check at my hand,

Actaully I already login after that pass out url.

Comment: Maybe you are getting some token on login which you need to pass in the request header

Comment: please share your code not by an image - just post your code directly here.

Comment: Actually I make a logic as per webrequest and get reponse and new code to developed so many ways but I m sure May be some isssue for header can you try at least in your editor. manybook.net login and try to above url. so you can get a idea

Comment: See in this video How to Call and get this url
https://fluvid.com/videos/detail/LjBaiXqEtY-ro--